# Expo ErrorRecovery unable to resolve

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This error happens when trying to view the app in expo.

`Unable to resolve "./ErrorRecovery/ErrorRecovery" from "node_modules/expo/build/ExpoLazy.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.`

I have expo sdk 36.0.0

expo-cli 3.13.8

Running on macOS 10.15.5

I have already deleted `node_modules` `package-lock.json` `yarn.lock` `.expo`. Then `npm install`. 
I also cleared cache `npm cache clear -f` and running with `expo start -c`

`Unable to resolve "./ErrorRecovery/ErrorRecovery" from "node_modules/expo/build/ExpoLazy.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.`

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "jetify && jetify",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "sudo react-native start --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~8.0.0",
    "hermesvm": "^0.1.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "node-libs-react-native": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.19.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "~0.26.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-scroll-bottom-sheet": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "stripe-client": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.65",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-expo": "^36.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyAmazingApp",
  "displayName": "MyAmazingApp",
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "MyAmazingApp-app",
    "name": "MyAmazingApp",
    "icon": "Design/MyAmazingApp_app_icon.png",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "MyAmazingApp",
    "sdkVersion":"36.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "translucent": false
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.me.MyAmazingApp",
      "buildNumber": "0.0.4",
      "icon": "Design/MyAmazingApp_app_icon.png"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com. MyAmazingApp",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "apiKey": "”
        },
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": ""
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.MyAmazingApp.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/restaurant/handleBarcode"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "Design/MyAmazingApp_app_splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "entryPoint": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
    ],
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./Design/notification_logo.png",
      "color": "#0CD2C5",
      "androidMode": "default",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i’m fairly confused about what i am looking at here - this does not appear an expo managed project or an expokit project, but you are running expo start still.. it may be worth reverting to your last known working commit and going from there

Comment: This is definitely using expokit.

Comment: there is no expokit package in your package.json

Comment: Just installed expokit and still get the same error. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: my original suggestion stands - you should revert to your last known working commit and go from there. given that the expokit package wasn’t even installed in your project it’s hard to know the scale of what else may have changed since it was last working